# LayerUploadPanel not works

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, boundless-suite

how can i add a layer upload panel tool in my suite sdk?
The main problem is when i click "upload layers" button. Appear errors in the firebug. I don't 
know the reason why those errors appear

TypeError:b[e] is not a constructor...
TypeError:this.dataStore is undefined:this.dataStore.emptyText = this.dataStoreEmptyText; (in LayerUploadPanel.js line 327).

i'm not sure if i haven't added the necessary code 
to app.js. 
i want to upload mi own shapes from layeruploadpanel, but i don't how to do it. Anyone could help 
me please?

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  Would you be able to edit the title of your question so that it becomes a "short sentence question" rather than just a "single word statement", please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LayerUploadPanel has a dependency on [FileUploadField.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/ux/fileuploadfield/FileUploadField.js). To satisfy this dependency, copy `FileUploadField.js` to your `app` directory, and add

```
@require FileUploadField.js
```

at the top of your `app.js` file.

Comment: thanks  for answering so quickly, Andreas.
That was exactly the problem, but it appeared another one.
 I can't  upload the map with the files .shp .shx .prj .dbf; then appears that message: (!) "source cities.zip is INCOMPLETE".
I have tried several times with different files, but it always appears the same message.
I can't solve it on my own.
Thank you for helping.

Álvaro

Comment: You can go to the GeoServer Importer UI to see why the source is incomplete. I seem to remember that this can happen when GeoServer does not recognize a PRJ file.

Comment: It is possible, but I have tried upload other maps as nyc_roads.zip and this is uploaded perfectly into my suite and into
http://suite.opengeo.org/geoexplorer/composer/
 
but, for example medford_citylimits is uploaded into the composer, but not into my suite.
Always appears the next failure "cities.zip is INCOMPLETE",  but if I try upload the zip without the file .prj, appears "cities.shp is INCOMPLETE".

Comment: On the Geoserver Importer UI appear these failures:
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [MarkupContainer [Component id = kml.regionateAttribute]]
        at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2725)
        at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1538)......
 
I thought that it would be a failure, because of the kind of projection  EPGS:4326, but it doen't meanto be that.
 
Could be by anything written in the .prj, and the way geoserver has of managing that?